# Grails gorm for mongo plugin with criteria full text search

Tags: grails, gorm-mongodb

I use gorm for mongo plugin version 3.0.1. 
And have a domain model Post.

```
class Post {
  ObjectId id
  String content
  String status

  status mapping = {
    index content: "text"
  }
}
```

I want to use `withCriteria` method for my query.

```
def list = Post.withCriteria {
  and {
    eq('status', 'STATUS')
    ilike('content', "%${q}%")
  }
}
```

I don't find method `MongoCriteriaBuilder` for *full text search* in source code plugin.
Can anybody help me? Alternatives?

Comment: What do you mean by that you don't find method **MongoCriteriaBuilder **? Is this exception being thrown? Which version of grails mongodb plugin? Please confirm this.

Comment: Ohk, I'm not sure about this that if they have implemented it or not. Needs to dig down.

Comment: Thanks @ShashankAgrawal! I have written [issued](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB-396).

Comment: Okay. Added watch for your jira issue.

Comment: The full text feature for gorm criterias is very important. If you've much data you can't query text fields with good response time anymore. We have more than 20 million records in our mongodb and without having full text search a query takes 1-2 minutes.